# How can snow be falling with consistent above freezing temperatures?

Tags: precipitation, snow

I'm a keen skier, and I've often been happily surprised by snow fall despite temperatures of 1 or even 2 °C.
After some research I found that the explanation relies in assuming that these above freezing temperatures are confined to a layer close to the surface as explained here:
https://www.onthesnow.com/news/a/15198/can-it-snow-when-temps-are-above-freezing

However, today I saw the same phenomenon on a ski resort that reports temperatures at different heights, suggesting that the above freezing temperatures extended by at least a kilometer from the base. However,  there were fluffy snowflakes falling anyways.

How can that happen?

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Agreed. But I am not the one who is going to start to raise   the duplicate flag here.

Comment: Hi Jack, I saw that question but only read the accepted answer. So it is sublimation what keep the snowflakes frozen? That makes sense. Should I delete this question?
In the link I posted said that evaporation of snowflakes cools down the air, but didn't explain it can keep snow cold on warm air.

Comment: I found this link with a good explanation of that effect and even a calculator: http://www.sciencebits.com/SnowAboveFreezing
That's explain what I saw. Thanks!

Comment: No need to delete... in fact as I reread it, I'm convinced it's not really quite a duplicate... in fact I think there's something important in the data you mentioned.  I plan on piecing a quick answer together.

Comment: @Pedro: Reading through some papers, my answer appears not entirely as simple as I thought it might be.  I still may be able to work up a decent useful answer if you can tell me the location you were at